# Next js redirects wp-admin link to 404 not found

Tags: wordpress, redirect, content-management-system, hosting, next-auth

I'm trying to add a wordpress blog site to my existing next js site, and when I try redirecting to wp-admin it says 404 page not found instead of redirecting me to wordpress blog page, how do I implement that?

Ive tried to change redirect url with nested sub directories